# Central administration access denied

Tags: central-administration

We're having a weird problem with Central Administration. The farm consists of several servers, of which 2 are running central administration, loadbalanced.

Now some times, when logging in to CA I'm getting an access denied on my account (and other accounts which should have access). The weird thing is that only one of the servers is returning access denied. When I alter my hosts file to point the DNS name to the second server manually, I can log in and use CA without any problem.

When we reset the application pool for CA, the problem is resolved for a while. But after some time it returns again, I have no idea why.

We have several web applications running loadbalanced on the front-ends, which are having no problems at all. Anyone any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you using named host header for your CA web application?

Comment: couple of things to check...Web.config should be same on both server...AppPool account is correct and having the correct credential...also try to disable the loopback check....check the uls logs when its get the access denied for more clue.

Comment: Yes, we're using host header CA. Web.configs are equal (untouched), apppool account is OK. Loopbackcheck is disabled by default on all machines. ULS isn't giving us valid clues.